# Strategies to avoid adding try/catch to every method block in a codebase?

Tags: exception

It is quite tiresome writing try/catches in every method block.

Apart from AOP, is there any way to avoid this and catch all exceptions? Would it be enough to just catch them at the global error handler level (e.g. as in ASP.NET).

Thanks

Comment: This is C#/.NET?   Only in Java (due to checked exceptions) do you usually get the ridiculous number of meaningless try/catches.  What do you want to do in your global error handler to "catch" them?  Log them?  If so, that's a good use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best advice I've heard on the subject (somewhere on SO, actually) was "only catch an exception if you're going to handle it."  That is, it only makes sense to use a catch block in that method if that method has the means of handling the exception.  For example, if the method should for some reason *always* return a value, and the exception is either silently logged or somehow indicated in the value (such as an error message attached to some custom DTO or something).  There's nothing wrong with bubbling the exception upward in the stack and assuming the caller will handle it.

That's not to say, of course, that it shouldn't be handled at all.  As you suggest, the last line of defense should always be the global exception handling for the application.  All fails should be handled gracefully, but they should more importantly be handled only by the class/method that is supposed to handle them, which in many cases is not the method from which the exception originated.  For example, in a simple forms over data web app, the data access doesn't necessarily need to handle the exception.  It can add information to it if pertinent, but for such a simple app the global error handler can take care of logging and presenting an error message.

It should also be noted (I'm assuming you're talking about .NET here) that a `try` block need not *always* be accompanied by a `catch` block.  You can `try{}finally{}` to take care of cleaning up after an exception (such as gracefully closing an external resource) without bothering to catch the exception and instead let it bubble up accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David. Here's my basic set of rules, or ... like the pirate code, guidelines ...

- There should always be one global exception handler to catch runtimes and anything else that the classes cannot handle.
- Try/catch should only be implemented when you can actually do something about the exception. And No, logging the exception is not doing something about it.
- Adding a throws or Throwing a Exception or RuntimeException should be avoided. If you have a wide or large number of exceptions to deal with, create a new exception class to wrap them. Exception is too general and creates problems for other developers.
- Try/catch blocks are expensive, do don't put them in unless necessary.
- Never, and I mean NEVER !!! use try/catch for logic flow.

Comment: When you say do something about the exception, does that mean retry the method for one thing? Give some examples of what "doing something about the exception" means? Thanks

Comment: "Retry the method" is actually a pretty good example of internal vs. external exception handling.  If handled within the method, "do something" could be "log and return an error code" or "return a default value" or something like that.  If handled by the calling method, it could include "retry the method" (possibly after waiting some grace period).  Retrying after a few seconds (asynchronously I would hope, if a user is waiting for a response), maybe up to a configured number of attempts, would be a not unheard of way of dealing with a flaky external service.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it helpful to think of your code as having three layers, and using an exception strategy appropriate to each layer.  I wrote up the details in [Exceptions in the Rainforest](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/exceptions-in-the-rainforest.html).